# Estimate size of .tar.gz file before compressing

Tags: gzip

We are working on a system (on Linux) that has very limited transmission resources. The maximum file size that can be sent as one file is defined, and we would like to send the minimum number of files. Because of this, all files sent are packed and compressed in GZip format (.tar.gz).

There are a lot of small files of different type (binary, text, images...) that should be packed in the most efficient way to send the maximum amount of data everytime.

The problem is: is there a way to estimate the size of the tar.gz file without running the tar utility? (So the best combination of files can be calculated)

Comment: Some image formats are 'pre-compressed'; others are not.  Some texts compress better than others.  `tar` header blocks tend to contain a lot of zero bytes, so they compress well.  It depends how clever you want to be — how much CPU resource you're willing to expend working on sizes vs bandwidth. Given the file size limit of 64 KiB, take a conservative estimate such as "I've not seen worse than 6:1 compression, so I'll assume 5:1 at best" and try 320 KiB of raw data in files and live with a small amount of wasted space, crossing fingers that the result is never bigger than 64 KiB.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, there is a way to estimate tar size before running the command.

```
tar -czf - /directory/to/archive/ | wc -c
```

Meaning:
This will create the archive as standar output and will pipe it to the wc command, a tool that will count the bytes. The output will be the number of bytes in the archive. Technically, it runs the tool but doesn't save it.

Source: [The Ultimate Tar Command Tutorial with 10 Practical Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-tar-command-examples)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by "small files", but generally, no.  If you have a large file that is relatively homogenous in its contents, then you could compress 100K or 200K from the middle and use that compression ratio as an estimate for the remainder of the file.

For files around 32K or less, you need to compress it to see how big it will be.  Also when you concatenate many small files in a tar file, you will get better compression overall than you would individually on the small files.

I would recommend a simple greedy approach where you take the largest file whose size plus some overhead is less than the remaining space in the "maximum file size".  The overhead is chosen to cover the tar header and the maximum expansion from compression (a fraction of a percent).  Then add that to the archive.  Repeat.

You can flush the compression at each step to see how big the result is.

Comment: The maximum file size I'm talking about is 64 KB, so the small files can be around 10 KB (some bigger, some smaller). In the moment I'm generating packs of 64 KB and then compressing them, so if it is text I'm getting like 10 KB of compressed file (I don't have compressed files just now, so I may be a bit wrong, but it is around those numbers).